# Why is there no content in my Geometry Nodes?

Tags: node-editor, osx

I recently downloaded and installed version 3.6, but all the content in Geometry Nodes is blank. I still have version 3.5 on my computer, and everything seems to be working fine. I tried importing a file that I created using Geometry Nodes, and it displayed normally. However, when I try to add a new node, it shows that the node does not exist. Additionally, the "open recent" files are all from a long time ago, and not the recent files I have been working on. I had a similar problem when switching from version 3.4 to 3.5, but I was able to fix it by adjusting some settings. Unfortunately, (I can't remember what I did) the same problem has occurred with version 3.6.
Please help me find a solution. Thank you so much.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have a defective startup file. I would try a factory reset, or at least reset the startup file.

Comment: Thank you. I reset the startup file, it doesn't work. But I try the  Reload Script. And it works!!!